# Member's initialization in __init__() and other method works differently

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've stuck with this SQLAlchemy-Python problem: here's a class that should do simple update job in multiple threads

```
class InThreadUpdater():
    def __init__(self):
        self.portion_size = 5
        self.select_portion_func = db.session.query(FBPostStats).with_lockmode("update").limit(self.portion_size)

    def run(self):
        for post in self.select_portion_func.all():
            post.locked_by_thread = True
        db.session.commit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    updater = InThreadUpdater()
    thread = threading.Thread(target=updater.run)
```

But after finish there's no real changes committed to db. It works if I move initialization of
member `select_portion_func` to function `run()` like this

```
def run(self):
    self.select_portion_func = db.session.query(FBPostStats).with_lockmode("update").limit(self.portion_size)
    for post in self.select_portion_func.all():
        post.locked_by_thread = True
    db.session.commit()
```

What's the difference between these two variants? Why the first gives some kind of copy for `post`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> some kind of copy for post?

Because it **is** actually a copy - when new thread is created, `updater` variable is copied into another memory region in the heap on the new thread.  This is probably a bad idea to share db-connections in such a way.

Comment: Okay, that clarifies situation. Think how make it usable, thank you!